# mybatis <id> tag in <resultMap> behavior

Tags: mybatis

I wrote mapping file like below.

```
<resultMap id="fooResultMap" type="Foo" >
  <result column="NAME" property="name" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
  <association property="bar" resultMap="barResultMap" />
</resultMap>
```

When I get 2 record of same NAME colmun value, mybatis return only 1 Foo object.
I want 2 Foo object becouse bar's column is different.

So, I workaround below.

```
<resultMap id="fooResultMap" type="Foo" >
  <id column="dummy_column_for_unique" />
  <result column="NAME" property="name" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
  <association property="bar" resultMap="barResultMap" />
</resultMap>
```

I added <id> tag in <resultMap> and "dummy_column_for_unique" column is dummy(not exists).
I successfully got 2 Foo object.

I suppose dummy column result in null, and mybatis probably handle null value as different record.
But such behavior is not explained in manual or other resources on internet I searched.

Is there any information of this behavior ?

Answer (score 4):

In mybatis's mailing list, I was recommended to use row number.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mybatis-user/FAvrJ4piYlU

So, my final resultMap is like below.

```
<resultMap id="fooResultMap" type="Foo" >
  <id column="rownum" />
  <result column="NAME" property="name" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
  <association property="bar" resultMap="barResultMap" />
</resultMap>
```

And sql is like below(original sql is wraped by outer select sentence for not modifying original sql, and this sql grammar is for mysql).

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum, org.* from (
### original sql ###
) org, (select @rownum:=0) r
```

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

MyBatis maps the objects using the ID. If there is no ID in the ResultMap, they are all mapped in the same object. 
Your table should have a primary key, but I guess that creating a fake ID as you did might serve as a workaround.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Actually, my encounterd sqls are writtern by other people and complex(join, group by, union...),
so, identifying what columns make unique seems hard....
# But, legitimate way is to identify unique columns as you say.